Some variants of Central Limit Theorem and their asymptotics
I have been thinking about some "variants" of standard (Lindberg-Lévy) central limit theorem and how they behave asymptotically. Can somebody advise if I am thinking correctly?
Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. copies of $X$ and $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$ and $\text{Var}(X)=\sigma^2<\infty$.
Thought 1.
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2~=~o_p(1)}. 
\end{equation}
This is because $\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))=O(\sqrt{n})O(1/\sqrt{n})O(1/\sqrt{n})=o_p(1)$ by the CLT.
Thought 2.
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\sqrt{n}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^2-\left(\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2\right]~=~O_p(1)}.
\end{equation}
In particular,
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\sqrt{n}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^2-\left(\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2\right]~\overset{d}\rightarrow~\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2\cdot 4\mathbb{E}(X))}.
\end{equation}
This is because  $\sqrt{n}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^2-\left(\mathbb{E}(X_i)\right)^2\right]=\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mathbb{E}(X))(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i+\mathbb{E}(X_i))$, and the first two terms converge in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^2)$ while the third term converges in probability to $2\mathbb{E}(X)$.
Question Are the boxed statements above correct?

maybe for alternatives, think of the CLT as an another way of thinking about the maximum entropy distributions: for a finite energy and mean you got Gaussian distributions, but if there is a left-side restriction on the values the distribution could take (like a minimum value), if its too close to the median value the maximum entropy distrib would be an exponential, but is far away it would skew it like a lognormal like Rayleigh distibution, but also if mean and energy are undefined, you could have a Cauchy Distribution, all of this scenarios having their own versions of CLT

Yes, your thoughts are correct (modulo a typo in the variance). This is due to Slutsky's Theorem.
Proof of thought 1:
We define:
$$A_n:=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i)\right),\quad B_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i).$$
Then, by the CLT, $A_n\rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution, and $B_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability by the weak law of large numbers. So, by Slutsky's Theorem, $A_nB_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution. Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability, so $A_nB_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability.
Proof of thought 2:
We define:
$$C_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i+\mathbb{E}(X_i).$$
By the weak law of large numbers, $C_n\rightarrow 2\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ in probability.
By Slutsky's Theorem, $A_nC_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normally distributed random variable. Now for the variance: If $Z$ has a standard normal distribution and $c>0$ is a constant, then $cZ\sim\mathcal{N}(0,c^2)$. Therefore:
$$
A_nC_n\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,4\sigma^2(\mathbb{E}(X_i))^2),
$$
in distribution.
